# How do you select top 5 from two different companies?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make this 1 SQL statement where the Company number is 1 for the first 1 but 2 for the second one.

The desired result is to get the top Salesman from each company and in this case there is 2 companies, but I need a query that will pull the results (either 5,10,15) depending on the number of companies (1,2,3)

```
-- query 1
SELECT TOP (5) SUM(Deals) AS TotalDeals, First, Last
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(Deal.DealNumber) AS Deals, 
    Entity.FirstName AS First, 
    Entity.LastName AS Last, 
    Entity.EntityNumber
  FROM DealEmployee 
  INNER JOIN Entity ON DealEmployee.EmployeeID = Entity.EntityID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN Deal ON DealEmployee.DealID = Deal.DealID
  WHERE (Deal.PurchaseDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (Deal.PurchaseDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-11-01 00:00:00', 102))   
    AND (Deal.CompanyNumber = '1') AND (Deal.Status = 2) 
    AND (DealEmployee.Type = 'Salesperson')
  GROUP BY Deal.DealNumber, Entity.FirstName, Entity.LastName, Entity.EntityNumber
) AS ChadsTable
GROUP BY EntityNumber, First, Last
ORDER BY TotalDeals DESC

-- query 2
SELECT TOP (5) SUM(Deals) AS TotalDeals, First, Last
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COUNT(Deal.DealNumber) AS Deals, 
    Entity.FirstName AS First, 
    Entity.LastName AS Last, 
    Entity.EntityNumber
  FROM DealEmployee 
  INNER JOIN Entity ON DealEmployee.EmployeeID = Entity.EntityID 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN Deal ON DealEmployee.DealID = Deal.DealID
  WHERE (Deal.PurchaseDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (Deal.PurchaseDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-11-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (Deal.CompanyNumber = '2') AND (Deal.Status = 2) 
    AND (DealEmployee.Type = 'Salesperson')
  GROUP BY Deal.DealNumber, Entity.FirstName, Entity.LastName, Entity.EntityNumber
) AS DustinsTable
GROUP BY EntityNumber, First, Last
ORDER BY TotalDeals DESC
```

**Here are the results that come up with what I currently have**

```
Total Deals First     Last
8           Chris     Fluffer
8           Marie     Oberman
7           admin
7           test      test
7           Dave      Caves
```

**
From the first and then from the second**

```
Total Deals First      Last
1           MARK       O'DELL
1           Edward     Thatch
1           FranK      Cavelier
1           Chris      Fluffer
1           Chris      Farley
```

Comment: How many records you want in the result: 5 (both companies combined) or 10 (5 from each)?

Comment: Well five from each, but it would be nice if it would work in the case that there were more than 2 companies

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ok I did, hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

First, each subquery can be simplified:

```
  SELECT COUNT(d.DealNumber) AS Deals, e.FirstName AS First,
         e.LastName AS Last, e.EntityNumber
  FROM DealEmployee de INNER JOIN
       Entity e
       ON de.EmployeeID = e.EntityID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
       Deal d
       ON de.DealID = d.DealID
  WHERE d.PurchaseDate >= '2014-01-01' AND 
        d.PurchaseDate <= '2014-11-01' AND 
        d.CompanyNumber = '1' AND d.Status = 2 AND de.Type = 'Salesperson'
  GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.EntityNumber
  ORDER BY TotalDeals DESC;
```

To get the top 5 from each group, use `row_number()`:

First, each subquery can be simplified:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT COUNT(d.DealNumber) AS Deals, e.FirstName AS First,
             e.LastName AS Last, e.EntityNumber,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.EntityNumber
                                ORDER BY COUNT(d.DealNumber) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM DealEmployee de INNER JOIN
           Entity e
           ON de.EmployeeID = e.EntityID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           Deal d
           ON de.DealID = d.DealID
      WHERE d.PurchaseDate >= '2014-01-01' AND 
            d.PurchaseDate <= '2014-11-01 00:00:00' AND 
            d.CompanyNumber = '1' AND d.Status = 2 AND de.Type = 'Salesperson'
      GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.EntityNumber
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 5
ORDER BY TotalDeals DESC;
```

Comment: Well the desired answer was to show the top 5 sales managers for each company but in this case there are multiple companies. Would I make the company number a variable? Is that possible?

Comment: This returns 59 deals and I'm only trying to get 5 per company. Also would you help me understand what the Seqnum, T.*, and Partition by means? Was the Seqnum variable supposed to be the count of salesman? Because it returns 1 for each of the 59 rows

Comment: @Learningyouslowly . . . The key is the `partition by` clause, but  I'm not sure what the right one is.  From your text, it would seem to be `partition by companynumber`, but that field will not work.  It has to be one of the `group by`fields.

Comment: What would you recommend?